# xcolor Gray counts for colored pages (gray does not)

Tags: color

I noticed a strange difference between `xcolor` `Gray` and the standard `gray`.
I am currently preparing to print my thesis and (as often discussed in the forum), color pages are often much more expensive compared to black & white (BW).

So I switched my color setup for printing but the print service I am using (in this case: https://www.primydo.de) still counts pages with `Gray` as color pages. If I switch to `gray` instead, it works perfectly and the pages are recognized as BW.

I could request how they decide a page use colors. But since this is clearly TeX-related, I thought I should ask here first. Additionally, if someone runs into the same issue, it might be very beneficial to find an answer/explanation here.

MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
{\color{Gray} This page counts for colored pages.}

\pagebreak
{\color{gray} This page does NOT count for colored pages.}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `dvipsnames` options loads named colours all of which are intended for classical printing: they are *all* CMYK (including `Black` and `White`). This contrasts with `gray`, which is defined using the `gray` model and thus is black-and-white.