# Prevent xcolor from putting B/W pages to cmyk color space

Tags: pdftex, color

I'm using `xcolor` for color support within my project. When compiling the files to pdf, I obtain a file whose entirety of pages is in the color space `DeviceCMYK`, even the black and white ones -- seems to be intuitive, but let's my copy shop count all pages as colored pages. However, black is properly defined.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
    Test
\end{document}
```

Checking the color coverage on the page (`gs -o - -sDEVICE=inkcov test.pdf`; props to in [Kurt Pfeifle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/8747/kurt-pfeifle) his [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61216)) gives:

```
Page 1
 0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00009 CMYK OK
```

**Desired behavior:** I would wish for all pages, where the coverage of C, M and Y is 0.0, being in the color space `DeviceGray` or comparable (not being in CMYK color space).
As my document sums up to approx. 180 pages, I would like to come around slicing and manual conversion of pages.

**Questions:**

- Does this issue occur because of the color re-definition, that [Joseph Wright](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/73/joseph-wright) mentions in his [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/617501)?
- Is there any way to achieve my desired behavior?

Comment: The `[cmyk]` option for `xcolor` explicitly requests that all colors get converted to CMYK. If you don't want that, just don't pass that option.

Comment: Wow, how obvious... Thanks and sorry for that silly mistake...

Answer (score 1):

As stated by [Marcel Krüger](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/80496/marcel-kr%c3%bcger) -- Just do not ask what you do not like: Don't pass `[cmyk]` as that converts all colors.